# Angular 5 URL routing with a button click and retain the querystring params in the url

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes, angular-routing

I have a URL which is like this

http://localhost:4200/cr/hearings?UserID=61644&AppID=15&AppGroupID=118&SelectedCaseID=13585783&SelectedRoleID=0

The router module knows to display based on this

```
{ path: 'criminal/hearings', component: HearingsComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
```

but now I have a button click in which I want to maintain the querystring.

button html

```
<button type="button" (click)="addHearing()" class="btn btn-primary">Add Hearing</button>
```

typescript function

```
addHearing(){
    this.router.navigate(['/cr/edithearings']) // how to include the querystring???
}
```

**I want to add the existing querystring to above button click event 
then in the route module it goes to proper route, along with the querystring**

```
{ path: 'criminal/edithearings', component: HearingEditComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
```

http://localhost:4200/criminal/edithearings?HOW_to_add?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are navigating using HTML template, you can use `preserveQueryParams`="true"

Notice that `preserveQueryParams` is without a square bracket.

Eg:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/navigate-to']" preserveQueryParams="true">
```

In-code example :

```
addHearing(){
    this.router.navigate(['somewhere'], { queryParamsHandling: "preserve" });
}
```

Comment: so do this in the html instead?   I have a <button>  with (click)  ... function call and so it is in typescript then

Comment: SCORE,  TY very much.

Comment: @ScottLeary : Welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

```
addHearing(){
    this.router.navigate(['/cr/edithearings'], { queryParams: { key: value } })
}
```

navigate has a queryParams parameter

Comment: so it will add in all the existing url params?

Comment: You have to set it. Take the params from the url and add it to the addHearing function.

Comment: how do i set it?    key:  value     value is red line under it